# Mondrian olap - DriverManager.getConnection error

Tags: mondrian

In my gwt web-app i'm using Mondrian. I have a method:

```
private Result executeMdxQuery(String queryString, Schema schema) throws InterruptedException {
CatalogLocatorImpl locator = new CatalogLocatorImpl();
Connection mdxConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(createConnectString(schema), locator);

return executeMdxQuery(queryString, mdxConnection);
}
```

result of createConnectString(schema) is

```
Provider=mondrian;Jdbc=jdbc:mysql://localhost/dds?user=root&password=qwerty;Catalog=/home/vskovalenko/schemas/air_new_zealand_monthly_traffic.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
```

all data within it is seems to be correct (at least db credentials and path to the file), this method throws no exception, it just silently dies and doesn't tell anything. Where should i loock to?

Comment: No point having a GWT tag!!! This is just a server side issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [olap4j API](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/api/mondrian/olap4j/MondrianOlap4jDriver.html) to get a connection. This will allow you to let the application server manage and pool the connections to Mondrian.

If you require more control on the Mondrian server instance, you should take a look at the class [MondrianServer](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/api/mondrian/olap/MondrianServer.html#createWithRepository%28mondrian.server.RepositoryContentFinder,%20mondrian.spi.CatalogLocator%29).

Answer (score 0):

add the following snippet to your code and try again:

```
Class.forName("mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver");
```